# What $P(E)\sim (E \to \{ 0,1\} )$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, cardinals

i was asked to prove: $P(E)\sim (E \to \{ 0,1\} )$.

the left-hand side is the set of all subsets of $E$. (Right?)
What about the right-hand side?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it is the set of functions from $E$ to $\{0, 1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it denotes the set of all functions $E\to \{0,1\}$.

Note that this is usually rather denoted by *exponentiation*: $\{0,1\}^E$.

Comment: Often by ${}^E\{0,1\}$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

The set of all functions from $E$ to $\{0,1\}$.